# Babylon.js not rendering scene

Tags: rendering, babylonjs

I'm very new to Babylon.js and I'm trying to make a simple game with it, but I have a problem: It does not render anything at all.

Here's the playground link: https://playground.babylonjs.com/#R7BDW3#22

I modified the default example (the plane and the sphere) and tried to make the camera rotatable around the sphere (focus is in the sphere), but nothing renders at all.

I googled this problem for like an hour without any results...
Also I tried exporting it and running the HTML file - but the only thing I see in it is just the dark purple backgroud...
Adding `scene.render();` before the `return scene` in the `createScene()` function also didn't do anything :(

My browser console:
[image: Firefox browser console]
as text:

```
WEBGL_debug_renderer_info is deprectaed in Firefox and will be removed. Please use RENDERER.           thinengine.ts:1224:43
Babylon.js v6.16.0 - WebGL2                                                                        (5) thinengine.ts:10009:16
```

What am I doing wrong?